Where to begin in Computational Group Theory?
I'm coding a small application that looks for periodic solutions to the gravitational n-body problem. I'm trying to better understanding the symmetries of solutions, which is made up of the product of ($d$ is the number of space dimensions, $n$ is the number of bodies) the following groups:

Permutation of bodies $Sym(n)$.
Isometries of ambiant space symmetry $O(d)$ (translational symmetry is easily dealt with so I'm not including it here.)
Time shifts and time reversal (isometry group of $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ since I'm only looking at periodic solutions)

Given a few generators of a subgroup, I'm trying to find computationally tractable methods for the following problems:

Is the generated group finite ?
Given a member of new symmetry, is it in the generated group (membership problem).

I know close to nothing about Computational Group Theory, so it is hard for me to know what to look for. Can you please give me some keywords / pointers / references? Any help is appreciated.
EDIT:
A few valuable comments made it clear that I need to clarify what I'm asking. Some additional context first: like I mentioned above, I'm working on a simulation project (which you can try online at this address: https://gabrielfougeron.github.io/choreo/) that numerically solves the n-body problem. The numerical scheme is a rather standard Fourier spectral solver for the extremal action equations $\nabla S(x) = 0$. It so happens that imposing additional symmetries of the type $\sigma(x) = x$ on the sought solution where $\sigma$ is in the group described above translates directly to linear constraints on the Fourier coefficients. This allows me to reduce the number of parameters, reduce the number of computations and reduce memory footprint. This part is already implemented and works.
Very often though, a solution that was found without symmetry constraints will exhibit a certain symmetry nonetheless. I'm trying to write a piece of code that detects these additional symmetries. A simple numerical approach is to minimize $\|\sigma(x)-x\|$ given $x$, this works so well that I find lots of new $\sigma$ that leave my solutions invariant. Awesome.
My problem is that most of these symmetries are most often redundant: they can be written as combinations of other symmetries that are already known to leave my solution invariant. This is why I'd like to describe the space of symmetries that I've already considered (i.e. the group generated by the symmetries I've already found), as well as designing a numerical test for the membership problem.
Let me describe the same problem in a finite dimensional vector space setting, and not in a group theoretic setting, as well as what I would consider a possible numerical answer to give an idea of what I'm after.
Suppose that you are given a list of generators $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We can group these in a matrix $V\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{R})$. Given a new vector $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ you want to know whether it lies in the vector space generated by the $v$s. In matrix terms, this is equivalent to asking whether there exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $V\cdot x = w$.
A standard way to numerically answer this question is to find a minimum norm solution to the corresponding quadratic optimization problem. The corresponding residual to this minimization problem is the square distance to the vector space spanned by the generators. In practice, thresholding this residual is a very reasonable first step to determining whether $w$ is in this space.
This is super classical in numerical linear algebra and every respectable package does it very well, either using SVD or full QR decomposition on floating point representations of the vectors at play. Unless the problem is extremely ill-conditionned or the need for precision exceeds that of the floating point representation, there is no need to go further.
I understand that my problem is more subtle. Like Andy Putman mentioned, "in a connected Lie group the $\varepsilon$-ball around every point generates the whole group". In a sense, composition in a connected compact Lie Group like $O(n)$ loops back on itself, whereas matrix vector multiplications escapes at infinity.
Regardless, I'm certainly not the first person to ever wonder about these questions and I'm convinced there is an extensive body of literature on the subject. What I need is a few pointers, a few keywords so that I can find this literature and make my own research.
I hope I've been able to clarify the problem, please do tell me if this is still not clear.

Isn't this group uncountable? How are you representing its elements?

I "cheat": I use floating point numbers.

Are you using GAP?  Because it may be indispensable.

@G.Fougeron Then you need to be precise about the question - are you asking if the exact rational values represented by the floating point numbers generate a finite group? Are you asking if any real numbers which are close enough to your floating point numbers generate a finite group? Something else?

The question is not about accuracy of floating point numbers. Suppose $d=2$. I understand that $1/\sqrt{2}$ is not exactly representable, but it is still very easy to detect that an 8th turn rotation generates a finite group of order 8 .... up to say $10^{-15}$ error. The question is about efficient algorithms.

@G.Fougeron: If you don't ask a precise question, there is no way to answer it.  I've voted to close as "needs more details or clarity".

I think there might be a misunderstanding so let me copy paste parts of my posts that are questions : Is the generated group finite ? Given a member of new symmetry, is it in the generated group (membership problem).

@G.Fougeron: your question seems OK to me, but I think people want you to specify how you are coding a finite collection of elements of your group. What do you mean by the word "given"? For instance, the square root of 2 can be coded as an exact algebraic number, as a floating point number, or as contained in an exactly specified interval of real numbers. The suggestion to think about these issues may be among the "pointers" you need. But in any case, the available algorithms will depend on the answers to these questions.

I think many people on this forum will be very unhappy with your statement "it is still very easy to detect that an 8th turn rotation generates a finite group of order 8 .... up to say $10^{−15}$ error." To whatever accuracy you like, you can't know if such a specified subgroup is finite or infinite!

@HJRW Please do understand that I'm not trying to annoy anyone, I'm simply coming at the problem from the point of view of numerical analysis. I fear my lack of knowledge of the computational group theory prevents me from phrasing my questions the way you are expecting me to phrase them. Let me give a comparison closer to my field that might help : If I were asked "How can I know whether a floating point matrix is invertible", I'd say "There are algorithms for that! Try LU or QR decompositions for instance, but beware of conditioning". This is the kind of answers I'm looking for.

I'm representing orthogonal transformations as floating point matrices, satisfying $| A \cdot A^T - I| < \varepsilon$ for a suitable $ \varepsilon$. Their product is the standard matrix matrix product, with every calculation done in floating points arithmetics. I'm aware that floating point arithmetics is not associative, and all those caveats.

I think what you don’t appreciate is that these are subtle questions, and whether they have sensible answers depends very delicately on how they are phrased.  For instance, in a connected Lie group the $\epsilon$-ball around every point generates the whole group, so if you aren’t careful with exactly what kind of certificate you want for an element approximately generating a finite group then even the identity element will “approximately generate” the entire group.  Similarly, the subgroup membership problem is very subtle, and in many cases is provably not decidable.

(in other words, this isn’t the sort of thing where there are standard algorithms we can point you towards.)

Thanks everyone for these constructive remarks / critiques. I'll try to edit the question to make it more precise. Indeed like @AndyPutman puts it, I do not appreciate how subtle these questions are, and your input is really valuable in refining what I want. PLEASE do not vote to close the question, since if I were able to correctly phrase my question, it is very possible that I could answer it on my own.

In addition to @AndyPutman ‘s comments about the subtlety of posing the problem correctly, please note that the spectre of undecidability  of most decision problems in group theory hangs over your question. Deciding if an element has finite order, for example, or deciding if a group is finite, is precisely the kind of thing that is undecidable in general.

You still haven’t asked a question that can be answered; indeed, your edit focuses on your motivations but makes no attempt to make your question more precise. Whether or not elements of a Lie group generate a finite subgroup is a question that is very poorly suited to numerical analysis since it is maximally unstable: in general, any small perturbation of generators of a finite subgroup will generate an infinite (indeed, often a dense!) subgroup.  In other words, you’re trying to test whether something lies in a measure zero set.  That’s just not something numerical analysis is good at doing.

"In other words, you’re trying to test whether something lies in a measure zero set." Yes! And I don't see the problem with that! A lot of these questions have very good answers in the realm of numerical analysis. Invertibility of a matrix for instance. Maybe there needs to be bounds on the number of compositions of generators allowed in order to not loose precision? Maybe there is a notion of $\varepsilon$-closeness that is needed? Like I said, I don't know the field well enough to presume the details of the answer.

${0}$ is a set of measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Yet, it is very easy to derive a practical floating point test to determine whether a given number is $\varepsilon$-close to $0$ for sound values of $\varepsilon$ (say $10^-{15}$ in double precision). Again, I understand that floating point arithmetics makes things difficult, but a lot of questions can still be answered efficiently both in theory and in practice with floating point arithmetics. I really do not think the floating point nature of the representation is the crux of the issue.

It really is a serious issue.  As you multiply things out in the group, the $\epsilon$ errors will accumulate more and more.  As I said above, I really think you are seriously underestimating how difficult this is.  There are innumerable ways of writing a well-posed question of the form you are trying to ask, and each will have a different kind of answer.  My guess is that none of them will have efficient algorithms, but the other three possible answers ("it is an open question", and "there is provably no algorithm", and "there is an algorithm with terrible run time") are all possible.

(reading between the lines of what you are saying, my guess is that you think there is a standard body of work on this topic and we not telling you about it out of spite since you refuse to ask the question in a way we like.  I promise that this is not true.  All three people who have commented after Daniel Weber (who I don't know) have extensive experience with computational group theory, though all of us focus more on discrete groups than Lie groups).

@AndyPutman: I apologize for the way I'm coming across. I did not mean to sound rude or rushed, and I am not accusing anyone in this comment section of malice. I am truly grateful for all you guy's input, and while yes, I did assume there was a standard body of work on the topic, I did not dare imagine it was willingly being kept from me. I realize I was wrong to think my problem fell under the umbrella of computational group theory. Again, I do apologize if I've caused anyone distress here. For what it's worth, I am not a native English speaker, which does not help nuanced communication.

No worries, nuance is hard to convey on the internet!  And I totally understand how hard it is to communicate in a non-native language.  I once had to include a French abstract in a paper, and I sweated over it for hours!

Your question reminded me of one more reference (apologies if it turns out to be irrelevant). In this recent arXiv preprint -- https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.12943 -- the authors develop statistical techinques to spot symmetries in data sets. They may have to deal with some similar issues to the ones you need to worry about.

To address the specific issue of undecidability raised by @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda (assuming your matrices are somehow given to you so you can compute exactly).... The membership problem for subgroups of $O(6)$ (say) is certainly undecidable, since it contains a a product of two non-abelian free groups. Finiteness is probably decidable, using the fact that every finite subgroup of a linear group has an abelian subgroup of bounded index, but requires more thought.

@HJRW For the “more thought”, it think (?) it should be sufficient to take each generator to the $n!$th power, where $n$ is the bound you mention, and check if those matrices commute (up to precision). If they do, then your subgroup has an abelian subgroup of finite index. Then it just suffices to check that all your matrices have finite order — surely easy, up to precision, too?

Some links on computational group theory materials collected here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexandervc/growth-in-finite-groups/discussion/548005

@HJRW , Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda : Thanks for the pointers. I think my approach is going to be the following: For finiteness (understood approximately because of fp), try to build the Cayley graph of the generators "layer by layer", i.e. in terms of increasing generator word length. If the procedure terminates in a reasonable number of steps, the generated group is finite, and I've listed all the elements. This is $O(|G|^2)$ for building the graph and $O(|G|)$ for membership (aka terrible, and with all the caveats you can think of), but I think it'll do for my application.

@Fougeron: if that works for you, then fine. It sounds like you are only interested in membership of finite subgroups: this is an important extra qualification; it would have been nice if you had mentioned it.

As it was made quite clear in the comments, you are not at the stage where you can ask a sensible question. Thus, I am treating your question as a reference request. The first issue is that there is no canonical computability model when one deals with real numbers (or subgroups of $SL(n, \mathbb R)$). There are several ways to deal with this:

You can work with matrices whose entries belong to a fixed number field. (I am not sure you know what this means since your background is in physics.) Then one can work with any of the standard notions of computability.

Work with the Real RAM or BSS computational model, see


Blum, Leonore; Cucker, Felipe; Shub, Michael; Smale, Steve, Complexity and real computation. Foreword by Richard M. Karp, New York, NY: Springer. xvi, 453 p. (1997). ZBL0948.68068.

Work with the bit-computability model, see e.g.

Weihrauch, Klaus, Computable analysis. An introduction, Texts in Theoretical Computer Science. An EATCS Series. Berlin: Springer. x, 281 p. (2000). ZBL0956.68056.
Once you have some idea about questions which make sense when dealing with real computations, you can take a look here:
de Graaf, Willem Adriaan, Computation with linear algebraic groups, Monographs and Research Notes in Mathematics. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4987-2290-2/hbk; 978-1-4987-2291-9/ebook). xiv, 327 p. (2017). ZBL1518.14001.
Lastly, there are various software packages allowing you to perform computations in groups (written, say, in GAP by de Graaf, Holt and many others).
